# Why doesn't gcc call abs function?

Tags: c, gcc

I have some C code

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdint.h>

int32_t abs(int32_t x) {

        int32_t mask = (x >> 31);
        printf("mask is %d\n",mask);
        return (x + mask) ^ mask;

}
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        int32_t i=-5;
        printf("%d\n",abs(i));

        return 0;
}
```

and I compile it with GCC.

gcc -O0 -S -masm=intel

The asm code is in
https://pastebin.com/4TGpSsdd

Why doesn't gcc call abs function
but clang do.

The program doesn't call abs function and

execute code 「printf("mask is %d\n",mask);」

My gcc version:

gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3) 4.8.4

Is this a gcc bug?

Answer (score 3):

`abs` is a [builtin](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html) in GCC, but Clang replaces builtins with calls to their respective library functions.

To fix this, you can rename your function (which is recommended; see below for the reasoning) you can compile your code using `-fno-builtin-abs`, or you can mark your function as `static`.

Here's a quote from the linked page:

> The ISO C90 functions `abort`, `abs`, `acos`, [...] and `vsprintf` are all recognized as built-in functions unless `-fno-builtin` is specified (or `-fno-builtin-function` is specified for an individual function). All of these functions have corresponding versions prefixed with `__builtin_`.

The C standard states that redefining library functions with external is undefined behavior (C11 §7.1.3 1):

> All identifiers with external linkage in any of the following subclauses (including the future library directions) and `errno` are always reserved for use as identifiers with external linkage.

If you define `abs` as `static`, the call will not be removed.

Answer (score 1):

There is a function `int abs(int x)` in `stdlib.h`.

You need to rename your function.

Comment: But that's not why the function is not called.

Answer (score 1):

1. do not use standard function name. Many functions (including `abs`) are known well to the gcc compiler. They are called built-ins. So compiler knows what this function does and in many cases it does not have to call it.

If you rename it - it will genrate the call with the -O0
https://godbolt.org/z/dLg26U

if you want to have it called if you enable optimizations you need to tell the compiler to do not inline it. https://godbolt.org/z/aHaEik

```
 int32_t __attribute__((noinline)) myabs(int32_t x) {
```

Comment: But that's not why the function's not called. Can you provide some reasoning *why* it doesn't work if you use the `abs` name?

Answer (score 1):

> Is this a gcc bug?

No.

`abs` is a function defined in the C standard, it's prototype is provided as `int abs (int)` by `#include <stdlib.h>`.

However, even without including that header, gcc has build-in knowledge about `abs` and knows what it is supposed to do.  This applies to hosted C, which most users are using.

In non-hosted C however, the compiler must not make any assumptions w.r.t. the semantics of functions declared in the standard headers.  In gcc, you get non-hested resp. freestanding by `-freestanding`.

In addition, even without optimization turned on (`-O0`), gcc will fold constants.  This is because in

```
int x = 1 + 2;
```

you cannot do the initialization at run-time for `x` in static storage – as opposed to C++ which could initialize that at run-time in principle.  In you case

```
abs (-5)
```

is folded to `5`.

As you very likely do not want to use `-ffreestanding`, you can use `-fno-builtin-abs` to take away built-in knowledge about `abs`, same for many other functions.  Even with `-fno-builtin-abs` option, you can use `__builtin_abs` in your code if you prefer the optimized version of absolute value computation and no libcall to `libc.a` / `libc.so`.

---

**Addendum**  ad freestanding due to a comment: C99 §4 Conformance, says:

> 6. The two forms of *conforming implementation* are hosted and freestanding.
>      A *conforming hosted implementation* shall accept any strictly conforming program.
>      A *conforming freestanding implementation* shall accept any strictly conforming program that does not use complex types and in which the use of the features specified in the library clause (clause 7) is confined to the contents of the standard headers `<float.h>`,
>      `<iso646.h>`, `<limits.h>`, `<stdarg.h>`, `<stdbool.h>`, `<stddef.h>`, and
>      `<stdint.h>`.

Comment: Where does the C standard except freestanding implementations from the rule in C 2018 7.1.3 1 that library identifiers with external linkage are reserved?

Comment: I added a clause. Is that what you are seeking?

Comment: That clause says freestanding implementation must accept programs that only use things from those headers. It does not say what freestanding implementations do when programs use things from other headers. The rule that `abs` and other identifiers are reserved still applies, effectively. (Or, rather, if a program uses features outside those limited headers, the C standard does not say what a freestanding implementation must do, and hence the implementation is not required to allow the use of `abs` as a program-defined function.)

Comment: Freestanding does not require allowance of definition of `abs` in a program-defined function.  However the compiler must not assume anything about the internal workings of that function, hence must not fold it away.  Therefore, if you'd like, you could provide some dreaded version of `abs` in you library. As nothing must be assumed about `abs` (except it's prototype) the compiler is forced to link against the lib version.

Comment: In a freestanding environment `printf` wouldn't be available either.

Comment: @emacsdrivesmenuts: Your assertion that the compiler must not assume anything about the internal workings of `abs` is not supported by any citation from the standard. C 2018 7.1.3 1 says that identifiers with external linkage in the following subclauses, of which `abs` is one, are reserved for use as identifiers with external linkage, and nothing in the standard mentioned so far negates that. 7.1.3 2 says that, if a program defines an identifier in a reserved context, other than as allowed by 7.1.4 (it may be declared like the header declares it), the behavior is not defined by the C standard.

Comment: Clause 6 I cited above restricts section 7 for freestanding to specific headers, none of them is `stdlib.h`.

Comment: @emacsdrivesmenuts: No, clause 6 specifies what the implementation must do when programs use only features from the specified headers. It does not specify what the implementation must or must not do when programs use features from other headers. In other words, if X is the set of all programs that use only features from those headers and do not use complex types, clause 6 says a freestanding implementation must accept all strictly conforming programs in X. Clause 6 does not say anything about what the implementation does for programs outside X.

Comment: So it's unspecified.  Or implementation-defined at best.